# 1 Sided Limit Problem

Tags: calculus, limits

Question, $\lim_{x\rightarrow 3^+}\frac{5}{x-3}-7=\infty$

My idea with the problem was to prove $\lim_{x\rightarrow 3^+}\frac{5}{x-3}=\infty$, and then find a way to prove that the $-7$ is irrelevant.

Proof: $\lim_{x\rightarrow 3^+}\frac{5}{x-3}=\infty$

let $M>0$. Choose $\delta=\frac{M}{5}$.

$0<-3-x<\delta$

So, $\frac{1}{x-3}>\frac{M}{5}$

So, $5>M(x-3)$

So, $\frac{5}{x-3}>M$.

I don't know how to incorporate the $-7$.

Comment: $$\frac ab+c=\frac{a+bc}b$$